# Ford Focus DCT Acceptable Grounding

Tags: electrical, battery

On a 2012 Ford Focus with the Dual Clutch Transmission, DCT, with a Fluke 75 Digital Volt Meter, battery disconnected, I initially read 2.6 ohms from the battery negative cable, past the negative battery cable shunt, to the top transmission actuator. I scraped both test points before making the measurement. I cleaned the main body ground point and the two ground points under the air box with a file belt and wire wheel, cleaning the terminals, washers and nuts, grinding the paint off and putting it all back together with dielectric grease. I read 0.5 ohms after putting it back together. In my mind I thought this should be lower given the cable size.

The question is what is an acceptable grounding test for a Ford Focus or a modern vehicle?

- Is an ohm meter reading acceptable and what should I expect for a good connection?
- Should I put a current source on the cable and top of the transmission actuator measure the voltage drop? I am thinking just because I have a 0.5 ohm measurement, that doesn't mean the path can handle significant current.
- Does Ford have a procedure for checking the ground connections?

Comment: Disconnected battery so measured from the battery negative post to the actuator - what path did you measure the resistance of? Or did you mean from the negative terminal of the negative battery cable to the actuator ie the ground path?

Comment: On the battery negative cable connected to the car, there is a shunt. I didn't want to measure the shunt, so I measured from the metal that crimps to the battery cable, past the shunt, to the top of the transmission actuator.

Comment: Well I used to check the voltage drop when the starter was operating - based on I^2 * R etc if less than 0.5 V it was ok but check for intermittant connections.

Comment: Checking the voltage with the starter operating is a good idea. I think that would be a good answer to the question.